# Предложение синонимов к меткам [internet-explorer] и [vkontakte-api]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

[вконтакте-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-api) к [vkontakte-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vkontakte-api) — пользователи могут набирать `ВКонтакте` по-русски, и подумают, что нет специальной метки для вопросов, связанных с api.

[edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) и [microsoft-edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) к [internet-explorer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), ибо нет метки для данного нового браузера. Или же создать отдельную метку для Edge, независимую от IE, — как сочтёте нужным.

Comment: Лучше отдельную.

Comment: IE и Edge стоит разделить, да. Зря что ль Microsoft решила новый бренд завести и "начать с чистого листа" :)

Comment: @D-side надо завести общую метку для всех существующих и будущих браузеров от ms. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я за то чтобы основной сделать microsoft-edge. Есть ещё просто EDGE, совсем другая технология.

Про вконтактик-апи поддерживаю)

---

Сделал меткам краткие описания:

> Вопросы о мобильной технологии EDGE. Не путайте с браузером Microsoft Edge.
>
> Вопросы о браузере Microsoft Edge. Не путайте с технологией EDGE.

[вконтакте-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-api) не было ни на одном вопросе, а вот [вконтакте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5) есть много где.

Comment: Спрашивают, [в основном, про браузер](https://www.google.ru/search?q=edge+site:ru.stackoverflow.com&num=50&newwindow=1&biw=1429&bih=974&ei=FBMPV6KcKsOjsAHJu6uYAw&start=0&sa=N&dpr=0.9), о [мобильной технологии](http://www.ixbt.com/mobile/itogi2006/edge.shtml) нашёл всего [1 вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469146/Как-устранить-возрастающую-задержку-при-отправке-данных-через-edge-2g/504084#504084). Хотя бы синонимом к `microsoft-edge` поставить надо, поскольку, уверен, большинство пользователей будет вводить именно `edge`. Спасибо.

Comment: Лично я за простые наименования меток, — ещё пример: `brackets`, а не `adobe-brackets`, — поскольку они более распространены, и следовательно, их будут вводить чаще. При этом понимаю, что у более опытных пользователей, возможно, другое мнение. Спасибо.